# Alfresco, query with dynamic values

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis

I have a `Map` with different values:

```
    props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    props.put("cmis:objectTypeId", "D:ruc:PLICO");
    props.put("cmis:name", "PLICO_1.pdf");
    props.put("cmis:description", "Descr");
    props.put("ruc:doc_surname", "Rossi");
    props.put("ruc:doc_name", "Mario");
```

I want to do a query ([QueryStatement](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.9.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/QueryStatement.html) or other) that dynamically reads this parameters (some of them can be missing) and build `QueryStatement`.
Does it exist an easy way to generate the query `String` for `QueryStatement`? Or do I should iterate my `Map` to build a `String` containing all the parameters and values in my query?

Comment: honestly never try it but did you try to use `StringBuilder ` ?!?

Comment: I just searching another way to not build dynamically a String (or a StringBuilder). I was wondering if it exist a way to do add parameter to the QueryStatement without building a long String/StringBuilder.

Comment: did you find something new ?!?

Comment: I built it from my own, I'm posting my solution

Answer (score 0):

My solution, but maybe somebody know how to improve it without dynamically build the query string:

```
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM ? where ");
        String folder = null;
        if (path!=null)
        {
            folder = findPath(path);
            if (folder==null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            query.append("IN_FOLDER(?) AND ");
        }

        ArrayList <String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, Object> properties = loadAnnotationAndData(doc);
        String objectType = properties.remove(MyEnum.cmis_object_type_id.getValue()).toString();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : properties.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
            query.append(entry.getKey() + "=? AND ");
            values.add(entry.getValue().toString());
        }               
        query.delete(query.length()-4, query.length());
        query.append(" ORDER BY cmis:creationDate");
        System.out.println(query.toString());

        Session cmisSession = getCmisSession();
        QueryStatement qs=
                cmisSession.createQueryStatement(query.toString());
        int offset = 1;
        qs.setType(offset++, objectType);
        if (path!=null)
        {
            qs.setString(offset++, folder);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<values.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(values.get(i).toString());
            qs.setString(i+offset, values.get(i).toString());
        }
```

Comment: I told you to use StringBuilder